# Can't set SO_BINDTODEVICE for a socket on enp4s0

Tags: c, linux, sockets, clang, multicastsocket

I have an old code running for linux (ubuntu 16.04) that binds to a socket and set SO_BINDTODEVICE,

```
setsockopt(sout, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,"enp4s0", 4);
```

I have change the target to a new Ubuntu 17.10, and it fails with the error **"No such device"**, I have tested in this target using loop back 'lo' interface and it works.

The interface have the multicast flag enabled

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0a:cd:21:ac:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:1c:b9:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:1c:b9:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
22: macvtap0@enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:e4:5a:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
23: macvtap1@enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:a0:93:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

It fails in all interfaces but lo.

I suspect about the length of device name, so I've tested in a 17.04 and with the name "eno0" works, but with wlp5s0 (wifi) doesn't.

I don't know how to solve. Do you? Is there a limit in the length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working for longer name lengths because you're passing in the wrong length.

The last argument to `setsockopt` specifies the length of the option value passed as the fourth argument.  You're passing in a value of 4 for this option, so only the first 4 bytes of the string are looked at.

Change the last argument to be the length of the string:

```
setsockopt(sout, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,"enp4s0", strlen("enp4s0"));
```

Comment: Silly me! Thanks

Comment: @Mquinteiro Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.